# How to get list object in Array in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, list

I have List it contains Item Name and quantity.

How to get Item name from List in Label[] lblItemName array And Quantity in Label [] lblQuantity array?
is it possible to store those value in seperate Arrays??

Comment: any effort to show?

Comment: need more information: please post code, for example from `Item` and your List that contains items

Comment: Provide [mcve] code to your problem, see also [I downvoted because no example provided](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var IbItemName = yourList.Select(x=> new Label { Text = x.Name}).ToArray();
var IbIQuantity = yourList.Select(x=> new Label { Text = x.Quantity.ToString()}).ToArray();
```

This approach would be faster though:

```
Label[] IbItemName = new Label[YourList.Count];
Label[] IbIQuantity = new Label[YourList.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < YourList.Count; i++){
   IbItemName[i] = new Label { Text = YourList[i].Name };
   IbIQuantity[i] = new Label { Text = YourList[i].Quantity.ToString() };
}
```